# Format time range parameter Azure Monitor Workbook in custom endpoint

Tags: azure-monitor, azure-monitor-workbooks

Have an Azure Monitor Workbook with a time range date picker that filters Kusto expressions and metrics but trouble controlling the format in custom endpoints.  For example, the a custom endpoint against a REST API and a URL parameter value:

`Created ge {TimeRange:start}`

the resulted is

`Created ge datetime(\"2023-05-23T09:30:00.000Z\)`

whereas I would like:

`Created ge datetime'2023-05-23T09:30:00.000Z'`

Any way to apply a function on the parameter expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the default implementation of the TimeRange parameter formatter was built for KQL.

if you need other formats, there are things like `{TimeRange:startISO}`

some are shown at from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/visualize/workbooks-time#time-parameter-options
(i'll look at getting that list updated in docs)

in the parameter editing view you can see examples if you scroll down:

[image: parameter formatting options screenshot]

text form for searching:

```
When replaced in a query or text item, {timerange} will become:
{timerange} ==> Last hour
{timerange:label} ==> Last hour
{timerange:value} ==> > ago(1h)
{timerange:query} ==> > ago(1h)
{timerange:start} ==> 5/25/2023 8:27 AM
{timerange:end} ==> 5/25/2023 9:27 AM
{timerange:startISO} ==> 2023-05-25T15:27:59.833Z
{timerange:endISO} ==> 2023-05-25T16:27:59.833Z
{timerange:startUnix} ==> 1685028479
{timerange:endUnix} ==> 1685032079
{timerange:grain} ==> 1m
{timerange:seconds} ==> 3600
```

Comment: Nice!  Absolutely nailed it.  Thanks.  startISO worked perfect.

Comment: if you only need the date part, there's also `startDateISO` which isn't properly documented yet either